# import a schema but redefine a definition

Tags: jsonschema

I want to import [this schema](https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/blob/master/schemas/input/csl-data.json), and redefine the following (simplified) definition so that its value is a string.

```
    "date-variable": {
      "properties": {
            "date-parts": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": ["string", "number"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot modify an existing schema. You CAN modify JSON to create a new JSON Schema, because a JSON Schema is just JSON with specific context.

Comment: OK, thank you. Could you point me to an example of what you mean in the second sentence? Do you mean write some code to transform the schema?

Comment: Yes exactly that. Do the modification to the JSON before passing it to a JSON Schema library.